# Does the squashing commits deletes individual commits from other branches as well

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose i  have two branches`A`, `master`.

now in branch A i have these commits

`a` `b` `c` `d` `e`

Then the user squashed the commits , i don't know how but yesterday on his branch i was able to see `5 commits`

and today i see only `1 commit with message squashed commits`

Now i want to ask that suppose before squashing , i create new branch from hi branch

`git checkout -b B-backup`

then will those individual commits be there in backup branch or they will be gone as well if he squash them in future

Comment: What happens if you create a test repository and try it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a general principle of git involved here that answers your question:

- Commits are immutable and forever: they never change, and they are never deleted.
- But, with one exception: sometimes they do get deleted.

To get to the answer we have to examine the one exception.

Commits in a repository can be represented as a "directed acyclic graph" (DAG), with each commit listing its parent commit(s).  The first-ever commit in a new repository is a "root" commit and has no parents, and in general, each later commit has one parent (a "regular" commit) or two-or-more (a "merge" commit).  So when you create the repository and its initial commit, you have one commit node with no parent commit, and a branch label, `master`, pointing to the one commit:

```
o       <-- master
```

If you then add a new commit, you have two nodes; `master` points to the second, and the second points to the first:

```
o<--o   <-- master
```

Note that commits do not list their children.  Those have to be discovered dynamically.  Here we start from `master` and work backwards.

If we add a new branch `A`, coming off the initial commit, and add a new commit to that branch, it might now look something like this:

```
o<--o   <-- master
^
 \--o   <-- A
```

(Note that the root commit *did not change*, as it did not have to change: the newest commit lists the root as its parent, but the root does not list the newest commit as a child-commit.  This forces git to discover the branch graphs dynamically, but means that commits can remain unchanged forever.)

If commits never change, then you should ask: what *does* change?  Obviously, new commits can be added.  To be able to *find* those new commits, something else has to change as well, and that something else is the branch *labels*.

#### Branch labels move

Whenever you add a new commit to a repository, the current branch label—the one for the branch that `HEAD` tells git you're "on"; you're "on branch `master`" if and only if `HEAD` *says* you're on it (there is an actual file called `HEAD` in the `.git` directory)—automatically moves to point to the new commit.  So given:

```
o--o   <-- master
 \
  o   <-- HEAD=A
```

(same drawing, I'm just not trying to type in arrows any more, and I've added the idea that `HEAD` says "on branch `A`"), when you make a new commit, it goes in where `HEAD` says, and branch-label `A` moves:

```
o--o   <-- master
 \
  o--o   <-- HEAD=A
```

As you add more commits, the branch label keeps moving as well:

```
o--o   <-- master
 \
  o--o--o--o--o   <-- HEAD=A
```

If you add a "merge" commit, the branch label still moves forward, but still, *only the one `HEAD` says* moves:

```
o--o   <-- master
 \  `-----------.
  o--o--o--o--o--o   <-- HEAD=A
```

Here `master` still points to the same old commit; we've just merged it into `A`.

#### Some steps make copies

When you `rebase` a branch, git makes *copies* of old commits.  Let's say we have a new and different repo that looks like this:

```
A--B   <-- master
 \
  C--D--E   <-- HEAD=branch
```

(instead of little `o` characters for commit nodes, I've used letter labels this time).  Suppose you do a `git rebase -i master` to "move" the commit chain in `branch` so that it "comes off" commit `B` instead of commit `A`.  What git does in this case is to *copy* commits `C`, `D`, and `E`.  Let's call the copy of `C`, `C'`, and so on.

The old commits remain, as they're immutable and (almost) forever:

```
A--B   <-- master
|  \
 \  C'-D'-E'  <-- HEAD=branch
  |
  C--D--E   [no label: "abandoned"]
```

But, as usual, git moves the *branch label* to point to the new latest-commit ("tip" commit) on the copies.

The old commit chain is still there; it just no longer has a label.

This makes the chain eligible for "garbage collection".

#### Unlabeled (unreferenced) commits are eventually garbage-collected

An "unreferenced" commit is one that can only be found by something like `git fsck`, that scans the entire repository to find absolutely everything in it.  When there's no branch or tag label, there may still be a reference through what git calls the "reflogs", but reflog entries expire (in 30 to 90 days by default, based on various configuration settings).

Thus, after a month or so, commit(s) that were once "on a branch", but have been abandoned, get garbage-collected.  (The command `git gc` does the collecting; by default, various other git commands will invoke this automatically as needed.)

At any point before they are collected, though, you can add a reference to the tip of an old branch and prevent this collection.  That includes doing so even *before* the "usual" branch label is moved.

---

Thus, the short answer is "yes, they will be there in the backup branch."

Even if you did not create a backup branch in advance, if you used to have the commits, you probably *still* have them in your reflogs, and you can find them with `git reflog` (try `git reflog branch` and `git reflog --all` as well as plain `git reflog`).  You can then attach a label to them to make them stick around longer than the default reflog expiration time:

```
$ git reflog branch
222c4dd branch@{0}: reset: moving to origin/branch
9c0d6ac branch@{1}: commit: adjust file foo for stuff
222c4dd branch@{2}: reset: moving to origin/branch
fb45c22 branch@{3}: reset: moving to HEAD^
222c4dd 
$ git log --oneline 9c0d6ac
[snip - let's say I decide that's the one I want]
$ git branch resurrect 9c0d6ac
```

and old commits are now "resurrected" (and visible to "regular" git commands, not just `git reflog` or `git log --walk-reflogs`).

Comment: thanks torek , Suppose user has 5 commits and pushed to remote repo. then if he does `git reset --soft firstcommit` then make new commit. will those commits be gone from system

Comment: In general, no, for two reasons: (1) `git reset --soft` moves the current branch label back but the reflog retains a reference to the previous tip; (2) `git push` (assuming you push `branch` to `origin`) normally (opportunistically) updates the label `origin/branch` as well, so this label *also* retains a reference to the pre-`reset` branch tip.  (Try drawing this out on paper: each commit adds a reflog entry pointing to the new tip; `push` adds a "remote branch" entry; `reset` moves the label back.  Which label(s) point to the entries that would otherwise be unreferenced?)

Answer (score 0):

The individual commits in backup branch will still be there. @torek's answer is detailed. Here is a quickly created git repo with two branches: `master` and `new_branch`.

`new_branch` was created after 5 individual commits: `a.txt`, `b.txt` ... `e.txt` in each commit.

I switch to `master` and squash the last 4 commits. It created a new commit and `master` has moved forward by one commit:

```
GitLab$ git branch
* master
new_branch

GitLab esarupa$ git log
commit 8ce95c8d369b0f6ede43a6fc073ff84660a43773
b,c,d,e

commit edd73ce559ffc1276ae0adba1cf9cfda080162f9
a.txt
```

Now, switch to `new_branch` and look at the logs.

```
GitLab esarupa$ git log
commit 5d75559fbdaedee3b73a9b26f0ffcf87c37de7be
e.txt

commit 7ede26f50b0ffda58af8d32320e4f1e9dcc60a68
d.txt

commit a58d8ffcfd401c890df1fbe4c37142c4b0a53942
c.txt

commit 06fa5d9f21fb5759bae67547d802a31ad5112e7b
b.txt

commit edd73ce559ffc1276ae0adba1cf9cfda080162f9
a.txt
```

Your backup keeps it's commit history even while original branch's history has changed.